# why i can't see any visiting data in Reporting tab?

Tags: google-analytics

i had set up a google analytics account 3 days ago and i followed the instructions given from google analytics website. all goes well, but when i go to my google analytics account i can't see any visiting data. to be sur there is visitors i accessed my website from different places.

is it a matter of time or did i miss something ?

this is the Tracking Code

```
    <script>
  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

  ga('create', 'UA-68467341-1', 'auto');
  ga('send', 'pageview');

</script>
```

[a preview from my account](http://eissa-soubhi.com/files/ga.jpg)

THANK YOU.

Comment: Is your Property ID (UA-68467341-1) correct? Your code is technically correct!

Comment: Also check for javascript errors on your page, sometimes that messes things up.

Comment: Random shots-in-the-dark: check that you haven't applied any filters that would wipe out your data, check the network console to see if the hits are going through, check with GA Debugger to view hits as well. Make sure they are all going to the correct property.

Comment: I had a look at your website (from the url in your profile) and I can confirm there is no problem with the code and the hits are properly sent. The problem must be at the receiving end (see nyuens comment).

Comment: It moks now, i can see visits from the day when i created my account... i think its a matter of time to activate your account or something of that sort.

THANK YOU ALL